Ag-grid getting random loading rows in between actual rows
I am implementing server-side row model with partial option to enable lazy loading. When the first bath of data is loaded, it is loading perfectly, but once I scroll down to load the second or later batch of data, the data are loaded but I am also getting random loading rows. I checked network call, all are finished without error.
I'm using ag-grid community version.
Also tried using 'infinite' row model which works perfectly but is messing with the height & width of row/columns i.e. not auto adjusting with the content.
